# Hovering Div Shows a Hidden Div - Prototype

Tags: prototypejs

I have three divs set up in the following way:

```
<div class="outer-div">
<div class="inner1"></div>
<div class="inner2" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

I have the second inner div hidden via the inline style. What I am trying to accomplish is that when the outer div, or basically any of the content is hovered over then the inner2 would appear.

I am unfamilar with Prototype and having a terrible time trying to get my head around it. Missing jQuery but this time around Prototype is totally required.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
$("outer-div").observe('mouseover', function() {
    $('inner2').setStyle({ display: 'block' });
});
```

Comment: While I think it's close, I couldn't get it to work. Could it be because the divs contain classes?

Comment: sorry, didn't see first that you used classes not ids for the elemens!
but probably it makes more sense changing the html or add an additional id, because i think you just one element of all these divs, not many of the same class! so try it with <div id="outer-div">... same for the other divs!prototype's dollar function only works for ids http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework#The_.24.28.29_function

Answer (score 0):

Not too different from the other answers, but I'm just using the `inner1` class as the thing observed.

```
$$('.inner1').each(function(item){
    item.observe('mouseover', function(evt){
        evt.target.siblings()[0].show();
    });
});
```

- http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar
- http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/each
- http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe
- http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/siblings
- http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/show